# MS Access VBA Object Required Error

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Dim maker as String
Set Maker = Forms![A]![B]
```

I can't seem to get this to work. Every time it runs, it gives me an "object required" error. This is contained within a greater module, but this is the only aspect of it that is giving me a problem.

Basically, I want "maker" to be equivalent to the contents of a text box named B on form A.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not use Set unless you are assigning an object:

```
Dim maker as String
Maker = Forms![A]![B]
```

For an object:

```
Dim maker as Form
Set Maker = Forms![A]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Much appreciated my friend.